# What will happen if I set normal consistency level to conditional write (LWT)?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I have 6 node cluster with replication factor 3. I am using normal consistency level as QUORUM and serial consistency level as SERIAL.

I have a conditional write query (IF EXIST). What will happen if I set both normal and serial to this statement using datastax java driver like below.

```
//preparedStatement has a conditional query.
BoundStatement boundStatement = new BoundStatement(preparedStatement);
boundStatement.setSerialConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.SERIAL);
//is this required??
boundStatement.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
```

My queries:

1. Will the normal consistency QUORUM will be ignored  OR it will be taken into account ?
2. Should I set only serial consistency level in this case ?

I referred to below link but it does not explain much
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigSerialConsistency.html

> The learn phase, which defines what read operations will be guaranteed
>   to complete immediately if lightweight writes are occurring uses a
>   normal consistency level.

Please explain in simple terms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The serial consistency level is only used for the Paxos phase of a lightweight transaction. If that phase succeeds, then the actual mutation (read or write) will take place using the "normal" consistency level specified.

So to answer your questions:

> Will the normal consistency QUORUM will be ignored OR it will be taken into account ?

It will be taken into account if the lightweight transaction succeeds and the mutation is performed.

> Should I set only serial consistency level in this case ?

Every statement carries a consistency level. If you don't specify anything at statement level, [the defaults defined at cluster level apply](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.1/com/datastax/driver/core/QueryOptions.html#setConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.driver.core.ConsistencyLevel-).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: If you think my answer is correct, would you mind marking your question as solved please? Thanks :)